# Access VBA - Apply Filter - Multiple OR conditions

Tags: ms-access, vba

I converted my working macro to VBA script (also working) in Microsoft Access 2010:

```
   DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", "[Forename] Like ""*"" & [Forms]![StaffTotalQuery]![StaffTotalSearchText] & ""*""", ""
```

I used the same formatting (I believe) to try and extend this filter to work with multiple fields, though it doesn't work:

```
   DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", "[Forename] Like ""*"" & [Forms]![StaffTotalQuery]![StaffTotalSearchText] & ""*"" Or [Surname] Like ""*"" & [Forms]![StaffTotalQuery]![StaffTotalSearchText] & ""*""", ""
```

This is what I mean by doesn't work: If my data is: 
[forename] [surname] 
  alex         bobs 
  chris        dean

then typing, for example "alex", or "a", doesn't filter the results at all. On the other hand, the code with just one filter does narrow down the data.

Comment: Is there any error message? What you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: No error message.

This is what I mean by doesn't work:
If my data is:
forenames: alex, chris   |   surnames: bobs, dean

then typing, for example "alex", or "a", doesn't filter the results at all.

On the other hand, the code with just one filter does narrow down the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try an alternative method of applying a filter:

```vb
me.filter = "[forename] like '*" & Me.StaffTotalSearchText & "*'" & _
" OR [surname] like '*" & Me.StaffTotalSearchText & "*'"
me.filter =true
```

> EDIT

As @Andre has commented, I have used single quotes (apostrophes) to encapsulate my strings. Your vba should work with the following change:

```
   DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", "[Forename] Like '*" & _
   [Forms]![StaffTotalQuery]![StaffTotalSearchText] & "*'" & _
   " Or [Surname] Like '*" & [Forms]![StaffTotalQuery]![StaffTotalSearchText] & "*'"
```

Comment: The key is using single quotes as criteria delimiter, this filter string should also work with `DoCmd.ApplyFilter`.  @Idios

Comment: The second suggested method worked like a charm. Thanks very much, Andre and Liam!